# Getting error with two matrices multiplication (mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am getting the following error after running the training process for my network.

> RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (21760x17 and 18496x512)

This is the network architecture

```
self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2)
)

self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2)
)

self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2)
)

self.flatten = nn.Flatten(2)
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(18496, 512)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512,1)
self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()


def forward(self, x):
  x = self.layer1(x)
  x = self.layer2(x)
  x = self.layer3(x)
  x = self.fc1(x)
  x = self.fc2(x)
  return x
```

The input size image is 150x150x3. What causes this problem?

**Edit:**

The architecture is based on the model created in Keras. I need to convert from Keras to Pytorch.

[image]

Based on this, I created the network shown above.

Comment: Hello, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You need to provide the tensors you input in your NN, because the shape of your input is most likely not compatible with the definition of your model :)

Comment: It may be helpful to write out your logic i.e. why do you expect the flattened output to have shape 18496?

Comment: @DerekG, I have added some extra explanation.

Comment: Ok so print the shape after each layer and see which operation(s) results in an output of a different size than you expect

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by changing the forward method:

```
def forward(self,x):        
   out = self.layer1(x)        
   out = self.layer2(out)        
   out = self.layer3(out)        
   out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)        
   out = self.relu(self.fc1(out))        
   out = self.fc2(out)       
   out = torch.sigmoid(out)        
   return out
```